# Python - obtaining the sum of digits of cube numbers

Tags: python

I want to write a code in python to print The sum of the digits of all whole cube numbers in a range that received from the user. for example if he chose [1,100],
1,8,9,10 are displayed that are related to (1,8,27,64).

Comment: That is a nice project. I would go for it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it would be [good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to show what you've tried to solve the problem...and, if you allow me to give a personal opinion, you'll learn much faster if you at least try something.

EDIT: thanks to @Python learner, I misinterpreted the question.
This should go:

```
def main():
    low, up = 1, 100


    # list of all cubes in selected range
    cubes = []
    # go through numbers in selected range, check if they are cubes, append them to list if they are
    for i in range(low, up):
         if is_cube(i):
             cubes.append(i)

    # alternative way, using list comprehension
    #cubes = [n for n in range(low, up) if is_cube(n)]

    # once cubes have been found, go through list
    for cube in cubes:
        # convert each cube to a str, so you can iterate over the single digits, convert them back to int, and append them to a list
        cube_str = str(cube)
        digits_list = []
        for digit in cube_str:
            digits_list.append(int(digit))
        print(f'{cube} -> {sum(digits_list)}')


def is_cube(n):
    n = abs(n)  # if n is negative
    return round(n ** (1 / 3)) ** 3 == n


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice! but I think op wants to find the cube numbers from given range`(1,100)` not other way around

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understood what you mean :) If the OP wants to go from 1 to 100, they just have to select the correct values for low, up in my code. Then, all the cubes are calculated, and for each of them the sum of the digits. Am I getting this wrong? :S

Comment: I mean we need to find all the cube numbers that are available in given range and do the rest. For example,  it should return 1,8,9 for range(1,30).

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple for loop to find a perfect cubes in a range of numbers, and then calculate sum of their digits:

```
import math


def sum_digits(digit: int) -> int:
    sum_of_digits = 0
    while digit:
        sum_of_digits += digit % 10
        digit //= 10
    return sum_of_digits


def cube(digit: int) -> float:
    if 0 <= digit:
        return round(digit ** (1.0 / 3.0), 10)
    return round(-((-digit) ** (1.0 / 3.0)), 10)


def digits_in_cubes(start: int, stop: int) -> list[int]:
    result_list = []
    for i in range(start, stop + 1):
        cube_root = cube(i)
        if cube_root == math.ceil(cube_root):
            result_list.append(sum_digits(i))
    return result_list


result = digits_in_cubes(1, 100)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking one by one that each number in the range is a cube or not, Which is quite a **waste of time**, you can rather modify the bounds to know all the numbers such as raising them to the power of 3 will create numbers in the range.

The advantage of this method is that you don't have to compute the cube root of each number, after changing the bounds, you know directly which numbers are valid.

---

### Explanation

- If we calculate the cubic root of the start and the end of the range,  the new range will contain all numbers with a cube between `start` and `end`.
- If `start` and `end` are not perfect cubes, we take either the integer above if we are at the beginning, or the integer below if we are at the end.

**Example:** the range is `[1,100]`, By calculating the cube root, we get `[1, 4]`. Thus `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` cubed are in the range.

**Note:** This is only possible because `f(x) = x^3` is strictly increasing.

---

```
import math

start = 1
stop = 100

cubes = []
for i in range(math.ceil(start**(1/3)), math.floor(stop**(1/3)) + 1):
    cubes.append(i**3)
print(cubes)  # [1, 8, 27, 64]
```

- `math.ceil()` is used to round upward to the nearest integer
- `math.floor()` is used to round a downward to the nearest integer.
- `**(1/3)` is used to compute the cubic root of the number (raised to the power 1/3).

---

Once we have calculated all the cubes, we have to sum them up. There are many ways to do this, either by converting the number to a string and then looking at each character, or by successively dividing the number by 10.

We can for example use a recursive function, which adds each remainder of the division by 10 recursively, until the quotient is zero.

```
import math

def sum_digits(num):
    q, r = divmod(num, 10)
    if not q:
        return r
    return sum_digits(q) + r

start = 1
stop = 100

cubes = []
for i in range(math.ceil(start**(1/3)), math.floor(stop**(1/3)) + 1):
    cubes.append(sum_digits(i**3))
print(cubes)  # [1, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

**Note:**

If the bounds can be negative:

- The cube root must be calculated in a different way (using `numpy` or multiplying by `-1` the cube if it is negative).
- The absolute value of the cube must be used to calculate the sum of the digits.